# Function pointer as a member of a C struct

Tags: c, function, pointers

I have a struct as follows, with a pointer to a function called "length" that will return the length of the chars member.

```
typedef struct pstring_t {
    char * chars;
    int (* length)();
} PString;
```

I have a function to return the length of the characters from a pointer to a PString:

```
int length(PString * self) {
    return strlen(self->chars);
}
```

I have a function initializeString() that returns a pointer to a PString:

```
PString * initializeString() {
    PString *str;
    str->length = &length;
    return str;
}
```

It is clear that I am doing something very wrong with my pointers here, because the `str->length = &length` line causes an EXC_BAD_ACCESS signal in my debugger, as does `return strlen(self->chars). Does anyone have any insights into this problem?

I specifically want to be able have the initializeString() function return a pointer to a PString, and the length function to use a pointer to a PString as input. This is just an experiment in implementing a rudimentary object-oriented system in C, but I don't have a lot of experience dealing with pointers head-on. Thanks for any help you can give me.

Comment: Although you say you specifically want to return a pointer. In this case, returning a struct itself is far better. It's a cheap to copy struct, and there is no need for a heavy weight heap allocation. String objects are value-based: They do not have identity (address), but their equality is based on their content. You could have this sense of distinction in your OOP system too, somehow.

Answer (score 84, accepted):

Allocate memory to hold chars.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct PString {
        char *chars;
        int (*length)(struct PString *self);
} PString;

int length(PString *self) {
    return strlen(self->chars);
}

PString *initializeString(int n) {
    PString *str = malloc(sizeof(PString));

    str->chars = malloc(sizeof(char) * n);
    str->length = length;

    str->chars[0] = '\0'; //add a null terminator in case the string is used before any other initialization.

    return str;
}

int main() {
    PString *p = initializeString(30);
    strcpy(p->chars, "Hello");
    printf("\n%d", p->length(p));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Great answer!

Question: I need to call free(p), but do I also need to free the chars?

Comment: I suppose I need to write a destructor.

Comment: There's no need to cast the return value of `malloc` in C.  Also, you should initialise `str->chars` after you allocate it (ie. `str->chars[0] = '\0';`).

Comment: Does the function pointer `int (* length)()` need/not need to identify the `PString *` parameter?

Comment: @ephemera has a point. You have to use the full prototype of the function. I tried without specifying the function's arguments in the PString-structure and I get an error. If I write **int (* length)(PString *self);**, it works fine.

Comment: Why does initializeString use `str->length = length;` instead of `str->length = &length;`? Does it automatically get reduced to a pointer with that usage?

Comment: Why doesn't this compile (at least using MinGW)? GCC complains about `invalid conversion from 'void*' to 'PString*' [-fpermissive]` and `invalid conversion from 'void*' to 'char*' [-fpermissive]` in the `malloc` calls.

Comment: For me this only compiles using g++ instead of gcc and after adding typecasts before the `malloc` calls (`(PString *)` and `(char *)` respectively).

Answer (score 7):

My guess is that part of your problem is the parameter lists not matching.

```
int (* length)();
```

and

```
int length(PString * self)
```

are not the same. It should be `int (* length)(PString *);`.

...woah, it's Jon!

**Edit**: and, as mentioned below, your struct pointer is never set to point to anything. The way you're doing it would only work if you were declaring a plain struct, not a pointer.

```
str = (PString *)malloc(sizeof(PString));
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, Jacob. I'll go ahead and try that.

Comment: OK, `strlen(self->chars)` still gives me `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`.

Answer (score 6):

Maybe I am missing something here, but did you allocate any memory for that PString before you accessed it?

```
PString * initializeString() {
    PString *str;
    str = (PString *) malloc(sizeof(PString));
    str->length = &length;
    return str;
}
```

Comment: Stop casting `malloc` please. Don't need to do that in C.

Comment: Better handle  all warnings.

Answer (score 4):

The pointer `str` is never allocated. It should be `malloc`'d before use.

Comment: Replace `PString *str;` with `PString *str = (PString *)malloc(sizeof(PString));`
And ideally, call `free` with the pointer when done using it to avoid memory leaks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use also "void*" (void pointer) to send an address to the function.

```
typedef struct pstring_t {
    char * chars;
    int(*length)(void*);
} PString;

int length(void* self) {
    return strlen(((PString*)self)->chars);
}

PString initializeString() {
    PString str;
    str.length = &length;
    return str;
}

int main()
{
    PString p = initializeString();

    p.chars = "Hello";

    printf("Length: %i\n", p.length(&p));

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Length: 5
```

Comment: Beware! This leads to undefined behavior, since the variable `PString str;` in `initializeString()` does not exist, when you access it through pointer in `main()`.

Comment: As @Kupto mentioned since you aren't allocating memory to the pointer of the function there is really no telling what your program is really going to do. I recommend having initializestring method return a ptr to the type, and before returning it, assign the pointer to the function the function.