# Error: expected '(' to follow a function. expected a ';'

Tags: c, function, struct

I don't understand why this error continues to pop. This is the function i'm trying to build: /person is a struct. Person* is a pointer.

```
void(*CreateNext)(struct Person *this, int isNextNext, ...)
    {
        Person* person;
        person = (Person*)malloc(sizeof(Person));
        person = CreatePerson(person);
        this->next = person;
    }

The error is on the first line and on the '{'

//This is the struct:
struct Person {
    char* name;
    int id;
    int numOfKids;
    char** kids;
    struct Person* next;
    void (*Print)(struct Person* this);
    void (*KillNext)(struct Person* this);
    struct Person* (*SelfDestruct)(struct Person* this);
    void (*CreateNext)(struct Person* this, int isNextNext, ...);
};
```

Comment: This is not proper C; do you mean something like `void* CreateNext (struct Person, int, …)`?

Comment: @CS student  This void(*CreateNext)(struct Person *this, int isNextNext, ...) is not a function definition. It is  a wrong function pointer declaration.

Comment: It's supposed to be a pointer to a function. isn't it correct?

Comment: Post definition of `Person` and `struct Person` which can be 2 different things.

Comment: See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1350376/function-pointer-as-a-member-of-a-c-struct) for the answer to the question you are apparently trying to ask.

Answer (score 0):

You are declaring a variable (a pointer to a function) outside the scope of a function.

You want CreateNext to be the name of a function, not the name of a variable.  The declaration should be

```
void CreateNext(struct Person *this, int isNextNext, ...)
    {
        Person* person;
        person = (Person*)malloc(sizeof(Person));
        person = CreatePerson(person);
        this->next = person;
    }
```

BTW, you shouldn't cast the return of malloc().  Casts are evil.